# checked checkbox values in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In an application, there is a multiselect-dropbox. When get the values of checked items of multiselect dropdown list.it has,

scope.names = [1,2,4,5] Which means i have selected 4 names from the list. During On change I selected names to other say, scope.names = [3,4]. How to do this with angularjs controller? I am getting the following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.isChecked (mmMultiSelect.js:85)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12332)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (angular.js:12735)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14217)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14488)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:22954)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4409)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4095)

#UPDATE
scope.names = [];
scope.onNamesSelected = function() {
  var names =  scope.names //get selected name list in array as [1,2,3]
  scope.onNamesChanged(); 
}

scope.onNamesChanged = function() {
  scope.names = [3,5]; //need to check this value in UI.
}
```

Here is an html options from browser, checkbox when checked.

```
<div id="NameItem4CheckBox" class="ng_checkbox" ng-class="{'ng-checkbox-hover': liHover}" ng-tool-tip="" ng-click="onClick()">
        <span ng-class="{'selectedCB': isChecked(c[ngOptionId], c[ngOptionName])}" class="selectedCB"></span>
    </div>
```

When not checked.

```
<div id="NameItem0CheckBox" class="ng_checkbox" ng-class="{'ng-checkbox-hover': liHover}" ng-tool-tip="" ng-click="onClick()">
   <span ng-class="{'selectedCB': isChecked(c[ngOptionId], c[ngOptionName])}"></span>
</div>
```

Also, I dont have checked fields from html. selected checkbox been identified by class 'CSBSelected'. How do I implement in controller.

Comment: can you post the code related please?

Comment: do you want us to guess, what you written in code?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it looks like you are passing in an undefined into your controller isChecked() function. If this is the case, you could check for undefined/null. Alternatively, you may want to check what you are passing in is exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: Would probably help to supply the html as well. I'd love to help if I have enough information.

Comment: Is this enough for you.